# A Space Code Added

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

There is a space code “ `&#160;` ” in my web part. When i add a normal code in edit source, this space code is coming. What is this code ? Why can not I delete it ? There is no space on css codes.

[image]

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="Portal_29.jpg"/></a></div>
   <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="Portal_27.jpg"/></a></div>
   <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="Portal_29.jpg"/></a></div>
   <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="Portal_27.jpg"/></a></div>
   <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="Portal_29.jpg"/></a></div>
   <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="Portal_27.jpg"/></a></div>
   <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="Portal_29.jpg"/></a></div>
   <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="Portal_27.jpg"/></a></div>
   <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="Portal_29.jpg"/></a></div>
   <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="Portal_27.jpg"/></a></div>
   <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="Portal_29.jpg"/></a></div>
 </div>
```

/***** after save ****/

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
  <a class="thumbnail" href="/Sayfalar/">
     <img src="Portal_29.jpg" alt=""/></a>&#160;</div>
```

Comment: check there is no space in between your codes. and you have put semicolon after every line.

Comment: I tried everything so  `$(".row").each(function() {   var $this = $(this); $this.html($this.html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, '')); });`  This is good for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is this code ?**

**& #160;** is the **entity number** of non-breaking space `(&nbsp;)` that creates white space between words or web page elements and stops the browser from breaking a line in the wrong place.

**Why can not I delete it ?**

There are some problems with using the non-breaking space HTML coding:

- Not all browsers acknowledge the additional instances of the non-breaking space.
- If you get carried away with the use of non-breaking space, it can cause the horizontal scrollbar to appear, if the browser window is not big enough.
- Using the non-breaking space HTML coding within the text or between pictures (for example) can make your content overlap the borders of the table.

To remove it, you can achieve that via Jquery as mentioned in this question at  [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549524/removing-non-break-spaces-in-javascript)

For more details check [Non-Breaking Space in HTML](http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/non-breaking-space.htm)